# Web scraping - Data repeats in long polling

Tags: php, ajax, long-polling

I'm doing something that involves long polling. What it basically does is **scrape** the data from the cricket website and post it in the telegram group. I also coded a mechanism that posts the score in the group only when there is a change in the score or over. Everything works perfectly except that score repeats sometimes for no reason. What could be the possible reason for it, is it because of scraping? but it happens only sometimes

Something like this

5 score,
2 score,
5 score (repeated)

Here is my code

```
<?php



include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$token = 'xyz';
$group_name = 'xyz';

$cricket = file_get_html(url); // scrape data from cricket website

$score = $cricket->find('.team-score',0)->plaintext;

$old_score = file_get_contents('old_score.txt');

        
if($score != $old_score){
  $bot = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$group_name}&text={$score}";
  $hit = file_get_contents($bot);   

  $old_score = file_put_contents("old_score.txt",$score);   
}     


?>
```

Ajax // this would check the above file after every 1 second (long polling)

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         setInterval(function(){
             $.ajax({
                url: 'score.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                  console.log('success'); 
                }
             });
         }, 1000); 
      });
      </script>
```

repetition of data screenshot
[image]

Comment: `$cricket = file_get_html('url);` Syntax error. Hmmm got yourself a new Account I see

Comment: `$_SESSION['old_score'] = $score;` Should really be inside the IF

Comment: Might be worth trimming and converting `$score` to a number before comparing

Comment: Sessions are unique per-user, so you'll get as many updates to the telegram channel as there are people touching the page. Also, relying on a user to have a page open to run javascript to trigger PHP to scrape a websites once per second is a _very_ roundabout way to make a cricket score bot. Maybe just run a background process on the server that does it.

Comment: Yesss! I had to! Stackoverflow plays a big part in my life to fix silly mistakes! Haha, So you are saying that data repeats (only sometimes) because I kept it outside the if statement?   @RiggsFolly

Comment: I kept the session inside the if statement. I found the repetition of data has been reduced but it still repeats (once in over) @RiggsFolly

Comment: Are you suggesting me to do it without the ajax? If yes, it could create lots of problems like 502 error bad gateway or maximum execution time(client request instead of doing from the server) ? Ajax (client request) prevents the script from those errors @Sammitch

Comment: I'm saying don't invoke it via a web request at all. Run it on the server in the background.

Comment: and can I know what difference it would make? (I mean how it would benefit me by doing this) Thank you @Sammitch

Comment: It means that you can have a long running process that isn't subject to the constraints of running in a web server context, [eg: request timeout] and you also don't have a browser window sitting open 24x7 to make sure that your telegram bot works.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a `while(true) { /*code*/ sleep(1); }`, run it, and forget about it.

Comment: Understood! Thank you! But I'm wondering if there is any solution for stopping the repetition of the score (it happens sometimes, not frequently) @Sammitch

Comment: as you said earlier that it is happening because of sessions (unique per user) what If I do it using a database instead of relying on sessions to store the previous score? Would that solve the problem? @Sammitch

Comment: Update:- I have also trimmed it but the repetition issue still occurring @RiggsFolly

Comment: I believe I suggested the same as @Sammitch on this question when asked on your other account.

Comment: As far as I remember, you suggested me to remember the last score (store it in the session) and it worked but sometimes it repeats the old score. That's why I posted this question @RiggsFolly

Comment: What solution you are exactly recommending me to sort this problem? (the trim one didn't worked) @RiggsFolly

Comment: and it has nothing to do with the telegram. When I echo $score inside the if statement instead of sending the score on the telegram, I found out that the same repetition problem still occurring (don't know why it sometimes pick the old score) @RiggsFolly

Comment: So what I'm saying is that it still pick up the old score (whether I send it to the telegram group or not) @Sammitch

Comment: Is it just you or can anybody run this page on your webs site

Comment: Only me! For now, I'm testing it on my localhost (xampp) Once the script is ready, I will shift it to the live server (run it on the server in the background, cron job) @RiggsFolly

Comment: I would do that, the CRON jon in background on the server

Comment: Yess! The script works perfectly except for the repetition of data. I guess the problem lies in session. I'm trying to figure it out from yesterday but nothing worked out till now.    @RiggsFolly

Comment: I attached the screenshot. It happens once or twice in an over and sometimes complete over goes smoothly (without repetition) @RiggsFolly

Comment: I also checked it with only over (Only digits) and the repetition of data still happens @RiggsFolly

Comment: keeping it simple rather than firing up a daemon. Just don't store in session, instead just write to file, `$old_score = file_get_contents('old_score.txt')` first, grab the score, if it's not the same as `$old_score`, post to chat, then file_put_contents the new score.. additionally you could check the age of the file with filemtime and not hammer the other site if its less then 60seconds old etc... or use a database

Comment: Hi! I did what you said but same problem still occurring (maybe I'm doing it wrong way, let me update my code, so you can see it whether I'm doing it correctly or not) @LawrenceCherone

Comment: You can check it now (it still repeats the score sometimes) @LawrenceCherone

Comment: In case, if you are thinking that the website is providing wrong data (repeated data), I  tried scraping on another cricket website too, the same problem occurs there too @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Looks like I found out where the problem lies! I was looking at the wrong place! $score = $cricket->find('.team-score',0)->plaintext; (I keep reloading the browser manually to hit the URL and then found out that it ($cricket) sometimes echo the previous score) So it means... it has nothing to do with the session @RiggsFolly